# as in the python bot, can I attach buttons as in the example to a webhook?

Tags: python, discord.py, bots

[example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0xokr.png)

how to create buttons in webhook message (add buttons to a view)

```
webhook = DiscordWebhook(url='link')

@client.command()
async def qube(embed): 
    embed = DiscordEmbed(title='Your Title', description='Lorem ipsum dolor sit', color='03b2f8')
    webhook.add_embed(embed)
    response = webhook.execute()
```

```
view=Buttons() not working.
```

```
class Buttons(discord.ui.View)
```

I don't understand and is it possible in python?

how to push buttons

```
@client.command()
async def qube(ctx):
    webhook = await client.fetch_webhook(1071845923254173746)
    await webhook.send("Hello World!", view=Buttons())
```

Is helping to send webhook, but dont view a buttons.

Comment: What do you mean exactly by "how to push buttons"? Are you trying to get a bot to push an existing button? Respond to buttons pressed in a webhook? Or just add buttons to a view? Please can you update your questions with further clarifications?

Comment: ready12312313123

Comment: This isn't a helpful response. Is that meant to be answer to a question I asked?

Comment: There is a photo(example) there, this is the effect I want to achieve. That is, attach the buttons to the webhook.
Sorry for the incorrect answer.

Comment: Well, what is `Buttons`? You've only provided the first line of a class and nothing else. what part of it are you struggling with?

Comment: The Buttons class is registered with me, I just gave its name as an example. I would like to learn how to make the Buttons class join it when creating a webhook

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have your [webhook](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api.html?highlight=webhook#discord.Webhook) defined somewhere - you can just use the [`send`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api.html?highlight=webhook#discord.Webhook.send) method.

```
@client.command()
async def qube(ctx): 
    embed = DiscordEmbed(title='Your Title', description='Lorem ipsum dolor sit', color='03b2f8')
    view = Buttons()
    await webhook.send(embed=embed, view=view)
```

Comment: discord.ext.commands.errors.CommandInvokeError: Command raised an exception: AttributeError: 'DiscordWebhook' object has no attribute 'send'

Comment: Well, that's not a `discord.py` object. Where have you defined that?

Comment: https://i.imgur.com/RRM1IqD.png

Comment: its a Bot.py object [image](https://i.imgur.com/RRM1IqD.png)

Comment: And what's a `bot.py` object? What library is that? Where did you get it from?

Comment: When I launch the bot, it is written to the terminal.

Comment: bot.py - it contains the entire bot code

Comment: Okay, but surely, at some point there's a place where you do `webhook = SOMETHING` What is that something? Why can't you just add that line or two of code to the question? Cryptically giving an image of your console output when you run the code isn't particularly helpful in anyway shape or form.

Comment: Sorry, I just don't really understand the site, and I don't really understand what needs to be written and what doesn't. I have a webhook variable declared.

webhook = DiscordWebhook(url='link')

Comment: Okay thank you. Is that from [this](https://pypi.org/project/discord-webhook/) library? Why not use the [Webhook](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api.html#discord.Webhook.from_url) object in `discord.py` if you're using that to have your bot?

Comment: I don't really understand this topic, it's something new for me. And by this you mean create a separate file and then access it?

Now I'm not quite sure I'm using that. 
I have two things.
from discord import Webhook and

from discord_webhook import DiscordWebhook, DiscordEmbed

Comment: Right, well the webhook object you're using isn't the `discord.py` one; the code I wrote will only work with the `discord.py` Webhook object. You'll need to create a `discord.py` Webhook rather than using one from another library. This is the same for the `DiscordEmbed`. You should be using one from `discord.py`.

Comment: could you give a guide or explain how to do it?